# PostgreSQL HASH index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, database

Does anyone know a situation where a PostgreSQL HASH should be used instead of a B-TREE for it seems to me that these things are a trap. They are take way more time to CREATE or maintain than a B-TREE (at least 10 times more), they also take more space (for one of my table.columns, a B-TREE takes up 240 MB, while a HASH would take 4 GB) and I seem to have understood from my googling, that they do not SELECT faster than B-TREEs; yet the HASH may have recently been optimized or google was wrong.

Anyway, I wanted you guy's opinions and experiences. If these HASHs are evil, people should know.

Thanks
Also: what about MySQL's HASHs?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Hashes are faster than B-Trees for cases where you have a known key value, especially a known unique value.

Hashes should be used if the column in question is *never* intended to be scanned comparatively with `<` or `>` commands.

Hashes are `O(1)` complexity, B-Trees are `O(log n)` complexity ( iirc ) , ergo, for large tables with unique entries, fetching an `ITEM="foo"`, they will be the most efficient way of looking it up.

This is *especially* practical when these unique fields are used on a join condition.

Comment: Indeed, this is pretty much what I thought before looking into the views of PostgreSQL developers. But it seems that even for the situation you have described, HASHs do not surpass B-TREEs in terms of efficiency and effectiveness for it seems the theoretical algorithm was not so practical. Thx

Comment: It should be noted that as of version 8.4 the issue with Hash indexes being less efficient and slower than b-tree indexes is resolved. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/release-8-4.html#AEN95616

Comment: Just one question, as far as I know, a binary tree search is O(logn), not O(n*logn), am i right?

Comment: Hasing is `O(1)` _in memory_, but with a database, the data is often on disk, the index might also be on disk, and disk access time >> RAM access time. I don't recall from database class exactly how this worked, but it's not `O(1)` in some cases. I'd still expect hash to be much faster, but in Postgres 9.5, hash is reportedly only barely faster than b-tree, plus it's not totally crash-safe.

Comment: Yeah. In truth you seldom get "real world" constant-time performance, there's always some reality underneath things that makes things hard.

Like, Memory access may be `O(1)`, but depending on which memory your talking about, that can be very large or very small values of `1` ;).  L1/L2/L3/Ram/Swap are not all the same speed, but the algorithm itself is still considered `O(1)`.

Comment: Is there an issue with sorting when using Hash index?

Answer (score 5):

As http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createindex.html point Hash index are still not WAL-safe; which means that they are not 100% reliable for crashes (index has to be reconstructed and wrong response could happen on replications). Check also http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/wal-intro.html

Comment: This is also true for streaming or file-based replication and is still true in version 9.5. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-types.html

Comment: This is no longer true as of v10. https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgresqls-hash-indexes-are-now-cool

Answer (score 5):

It's better to use a Hash index for text columns that are searched using = operator only. For example a URL column which needs to be indexed for lookups.

A Hash index is approximately 30% the size of a B-Tree index for something like a URL.

The reduced size allows PostgreSQL to use it's cache memory (Aka, shared_buffers) more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but am considering this approach, to use hash indexes on non-logged temp tables.

My understanding is that they build faster, take less space & query slightly faster than b-tree.

According to [this benchmark](http://www.depesz.com/2010/06/28/should-you-use-hash-index/), hash indices are a bit faster and somewhat smaller than BTree indices. However, you can't make a unique hash index with them -- additionally they are not WAL-logged.